# Vertical Asymptote Trigonometry Question

Tags: trigonometry

Question: Suppose you compressed the function $ = sec()$ horizontally by factor of 2. Will it
still have the same vertical asymptotes? Explain. If not, list all vertical asymptotes in
the interval $[0, 2]$.

I am a bit confused on what the question is asking me and I don't know how to solve for the vertical asymptotes in an interval. If anyone can help me out, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Let us suppose you were working with only $y=\sec x$ without the horizontal dilation.  Where are the vertical asymptotes?  Recall:  $\sec x=\dfrac1{\cos x}$.

Comment: just take any plotter on the net and let ist plot sec(2x), than you see everything asked

Answer (score 1):

[image: sec(x) green, sec(2x) red.]

I hope you see everything asked

Comment: Oh. Now I get it and I can see the vertical asymptotes. It won't have the same asymptotes because if the parabola compresses, the asymptotes will be farther away than if the parabola doesn't compress at all. Thank you so much for your response!

Comment: ypir conclusion is wrong ,  the  assymptotes are  twice as many, and closer together! you have to look for the negativ and the positive part of the graphs

Answer (score 1):

By definition, we have that $\sec(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$. The vertical asymptote at $x=a$ are produced when one of the following  behavior holds,
$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \pm \infty, \lim_{x\to a^+} f(x) = \pm \infty, \lim_{x\to a^-} f(x) = \pm \infty.$$
In this case, we are compressing the function $y = \sec(x)$ horizontally by $2$ units. This means that our new function is $y_1(x) = f(2x)$. The interval $[0,2\pi]$ where $f(x)$ is defined becomes $[0,\pi]$ for $f(2x)$. It's enough to check asymptotes for $y_1 = f(2x)$ on $[0,\pi]$. Notice that $$\sec^2(x) \to \pm \infty \text{ as } x \to \frac{1}{2}\left(2n \pi \pm\frac{\pi}{2}\right), \text{ where } n \in \mathbb{Z}.$$
From the last expression, you need to use $n$, such that $x \in [0,\pi]$. Hope this helps